# Named Parameters rather than positional for Spring MessageSource.getMessage()

Tags: spring, named-parameters

we are using Spring MessageSource to build error messages in our app.

We populate our error messages like this

```
dobInvalid = The DOB supplied {0} is invalid
```

We want to use named parameters so we can do

```
dobInvalid = The DOB supplied {dob} is invalid
```

Looking in the Api docs for getMessage it appears to suggest you can do this 
http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/1.2.x/api/org/springframework/context/MessageSource.html

> args - Array of arguments that will be filled in for params within the
>   message (params look like "{0}", "{1,date}", "{2,time}" within a
>   message), or null if none.

Obviously we can write our own but was wondering if spring can do it and if anyone can provide an example or using named parameters rather positional parameters.

Cheers
Mark

Answer (score 8):

AIUI, Spring MessageSource works with JDK [MessageFormat](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/MessageFormat.html), so there is no such a named parameter. `{1,date}` is an example, where "date" refers to formatType, no to an arbitrary named parameter.

The general form of a parameter is:

```
{ ArgumentIndex , FormatType , FormatStyle }
```